# Sending Data over Wifi From a client Raspberry to a server Raspberry and Writting it to a CSV

Tags: c, raspberry-pi4

I am working a school project related to a rocket and I need to send some data from the rocket(raspberry) to the ground computer(raspberry). I am doing test on a sensor. On the rocket raspberry, I am getting the sensors reading. But when I transfer them over to the ground I am getting a csv file fille with 0s

I have been stuck for a while here and i don't see where I am wrong.

Client side:

```
int sock = 0;
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

  // Create a socket
  if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
      printf("\nSocket creation error\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));

  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

  // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form
  if (inet_pton(AF_INET, SERVER_IP, &serv_addr.sin_addr) <= 0) {
      printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // Connect to server
  if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
      printf("\nConnection Failed\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

//Technical Part
  //CSV file
  FILE *csv_file = fopen("data.csv", "w");
  if (csv_file == NULL) {
      perror("Failed to open CSV file");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  //What's left to do
    int fd = wiringPiI2CSetup(LIDAR_I2C_ADDR);
    if (fd == -1) {
        printf("Setup problem\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int frm_activation = wiringPiI2CWriteReg8(fd, LIDAR_FRM_REG, LIDAR_FRM);
    if (frm_activation == -1) {
        printf("Problem with setting up free running mode\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int askMeasure = wiringPiI2CWriteReg8(fd,0x00,0x04);
    if (askMeasure==-1) {
        printf("Problem with measure asking\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while(1) {
        i2cResult = readI2C(fd);
        printf("I2C read = %d\n", i2cResult);
    fprintf(csv_file, "%d\n", i2cResult);
    if(send(sock, &i2cResult, sizeof(i2cResult), 0)==-1){
      perror("failed to send data to server");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
        delayMicroseconds(100000);
    }
 fclose(csv_file);
}
```

Server Side:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PORT "port"
#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 1024

int main() {
    // Create a socket
    int server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (server_socket == -1) {
        perror("Failed to create socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Bind the socket to a port
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    memset(&server_address, 0, sizeof(server_address));
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    if (bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, sizeof(server_address)) == -1) {
        perror("Failed to bind socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Listen for incoming connections
    if (listen(server_socket, 1) == -1) {
        perror("Failed to listen for incoming connections");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Waiting for incoming connection...\n");

    // Accept an incoming connection
    struct sockaddr_in client_address;
    socklen_t client_address_length = sizeof(client_address);
    int client_socket = accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&client_address, &client_address_length);
    if (client_socket == -1) {
        perror("Failed to accept incoming connection");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Accepted incoming connection from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(client_address.sin_addr), ntohs(client_address.sin_port));

    // Open the CSV file for writing
    FILE *csv_file = fopen("data.csv", "w");
    if (csv_file == NULL) {
        perror("Failed to open CSV file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Receive data from the client and write it to the CSV file
    while(1){
      char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
      int bytes_received = recv(client_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
      if (bytes_received == -1) {
          perror("Failed to receive data from client");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      if (bytes_received == 0) {
          break; // End of stream
      }
      // Write the data to the CSV file
      buffer[bytes_received] = '\0';
      int data = atoi(buffer);
      fprintf(csv_file, "%d\n", data);

      // Print the data to the console
      printf("%d\n", data);

      // Clear the buffer
      memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    }

    printf("Data received successfully\n");

    // Close the CSV file and the sockets
    fclose(csv_file);
    close(client_socket);
    close(server_socket);

    return 0;
}
```